# css hover over one element trigger another?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to trigger a div hover affect when I am hovering over the parent div

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="photo-container">

        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid photo" src="img/jay.png" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Jay Query</h4>
        <p class="card-text">
            Jay is a developer, author of CSS: The Missing Manual, JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, and web development teacher.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS
When I hover over .card I wont .photo hover to be active.

```
.photo {
    transition: transform .5s;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.photo:hover {
      -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.photo-container{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card:hover{
    //do .photo:hover 
}
```

Thank you

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 2):

Trigger child hover effect like so

```
.card:hover .photo{
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot invoke the `.photo:hover` state just by hovering over the parent element, however you can do this:

```
.card:hover .photo {
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `:hover` on the parent and give the hover styles to the child.

```css
.card:hover .photo {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```